# Issues with sharing an AppSettings.Development.json between 2 .NET core projects

Tags: asp.net-core

We have a single **AppSettings.Development.json** which we are trying to share between 2 .NET Core projects. To that effect this is how it looks in the .csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\AppSettings.*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Above does seem to copy over the AppSettings.Development.json files from the parent directory into the bin\debug\.net6.0 folder (which is the output directory).

However, when run, the settings are missing!

Now if I instead copy over the 2 settings files and keep them next to the csproj (and remove the above ItemGroup from csproj), then settings do appear when run.

What am I missing here?

I am just testing this locally now.

Comment: Could you share your code of program.cs ?

Comment: Qing, there is nothing in Program.cs related to these files. Don't want to add anything as these are the default settings file names that Core supports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share appsettings.json configuration files between projects in ASP.NET Core, I have a work demo like below, you can refer to it.

1.The shared file, logically it doesn't belong to either app directly, so we'll move it outside of the two app folders. I created a folder called Shared at the same level as the project folders:
[image]

2.Inside this folder I created a file called SharedSettings.json, and inside that I added the following JSON:

```
{
    "MySection": {
        "SharedValue": "This value is shared across both apps",
        "AppSpecificValue": "override me"
    }
}
```

3. The appsettings.json file for the Razor app would be:

```
    {
        "MySection": {
            "AppSpecificValue": "Value for Razor app"
        }
    }
```

4. So we can view the actual values received by the app, we'll just dump the configuration section to the screen in the Razor app with the following markup:

   ```
   @page
   @using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
   @inject IConfiguration _configuration;

   @foreach (var kvp in _configuration.GetSection("MySection").AsEnumerable())
   {
       <p>@kvp.Key : @kvp.Value</p>
   }
   ```

5.**Loading the SharedSettings.json in ConfigureAppConfiguration in Program.cs**: we've extracted the common setting to SharedSettings.json but we still need to configure our apps to load their configuration from that file as well. We need to get the path to the file, and add it in our ConfigureAppConfiguration method, right before we add the appsettings.json files:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// find the shared folder in the parent folder
var sharedFolder = Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "..", "Shared");
builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, "SharedSettings.json"), optional: true)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
...
```

6.If you want to publish, add code:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="..\Shared\SharedSettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I am trying to avoid #5 in your steps above, because the file already has the default AppSettings.json name. But, it doesn't work. Does your steps above work if you have a "shared AppSettings.json" file?

Comment: @cooper_milton Yes, my steps above work if I have a "shared AppSettings.json" file. You can try it.

Comment: did you remove step #5 and try with AppSettings.json? Please use exact file name.

Comment: @cooper_milton If I remove  step #5 , the SharedSettings.json won't be load. And each project should have their AppSettings.json, so I name the shared json as SharedSettings.json. Besides, the shared file, logically it doesn't belong to either app directly, so we'll move it outside of the two app folders.